# behavior for @PostConstruct exception handling in WebSphere

Tags: java, jsf, websphere-7, websphere-portal, postconstruct

Short: (Portlet-)Container swallows Exception thrown by @PostConstruct method in backing bean.

Is this behavior intentional, a bug or container specific?

Long: I am running a portlet on WebSphere Portal 7, where i force managed bean construction in a PhaseListener so it can send the user back to the start page, when the system encounters unrecoverable problems during Bean construction/post-construction.

I am using the following code to 'force' construction:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T getManagedBean(final String beanName)
{
    final FacesContext context = getFacesContext();
    return (T)context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{" + beanName + "}", Object.class);
}
```

I tested throwing a RuntimeException from the @PostConstruct method

```
@PostConstruct
public void initialize()
{
    throw new RuntimeException("test");
}
```

The stacktrace ends up on the RAD(Eclipse) log:

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper doInvoke unable to invoke method --> [initialize] on class --> [foo.bar.UpdateAddress]
                             java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.doInvokeSingle(WASAnnotationHelper.java:432)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.doInvokeChain(WASAnnotationHelper.java:400)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper.doPostConstruct(WASAnnotationHelper.java:220)
at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebSphereInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebSphereInjectionProvider.java:86)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:225)
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: test
    at foo.bar.UpdateAddress.initialize(UpdateAddress.java:119)
    ... 121 more
```

But there is no exception to catch in my PhaseListener and it happily continues without being aware of an Exception during the @PostConstruct.

Is this behavior intentional, a bug or container specific?

It looks like at least JBoss has a similar way of handling : http://www.coderanch.com/t/499013/JSF/java/PostConstruct-exception-handling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per section 15.5.9 of the Servlet 3.0 specification:

> The @PostConstruct annotation MUST be supported by all classes that
>   support dependency injection and called even if the class does not
>   request any resources to be injected.  If the method throws an
>   unchecked exception **the class MUST not be put into service** and no
>   method on that instance can be called.

If you're seeing different behavior, then this looks like a product defect.  If the servlet is not being put into service but the exception is being swallowed, this sounds like a serviceability defect.  In either case, I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM.  Note that it is unlikely that your terms of service allow decompiling WebSphere Application Server classes, even for the purposes of debugging.

Comment: Thanks one of my coworkers mentioned also that the class should not be placed on the session. But its definitely there.